# Use API token in axios instance in react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I am trying to create an axios instance that I can use throughout the app.  I used this same pattern in Vue using Vuex store but not sure how to do this in React.  I have an AuthProvider for AuthContext and would like to useContext when creating the axios instance but I'm receiving an error that I can't use useContext outside of a component.

What is the best way to accomplish this?  I have the user and a logout function in the AuthContext that I would like to use but this pattern may not be best for React.

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'
import { AuthContext } from "./AuthProvider";
import { getEnvironment } from "./environment";
const env = getEnvironment();

const { user, logout } = useContext(AuthContext);

const instance = axios.create();

instance.defaults.baseURL = env.apiUrl;

instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${user.token}`;

instance.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  return response
}, function (error) {
  if (typeof error.response === 'undefined' || [401, 419].includes(error.response.status)) {
    logout();
  }
  return Promise.reject(error)
})

export default instance;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want to couple some state and callbacks from another context then you need to create another context and axios instance provider of your own as well.

```
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'
import { AuthContext } from "./AuthProvider";
import { getEnvironment } from "./environment";

const env = getEnvironment();

const instance = axios.create(); // <-- create axios instance
instance.defaults.baseURL = env.apiUrl;

export const AxiosContext = createContext(null); // <-- export axios context

const AxiosProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { user, logout } = useContext(AuthContext); // <-- get state/callback

  // Use an effect to updated the auth context dependent details
  useEffect(() => {
    instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${user.token}`;
    instance.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
      return response
    }, function (error) {
      if (typeof error.response === 'undefined' || [401, 419].includes(error.response.status)) {
        logout();
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
  }, [user.token, logout]);
  

  return (
    <AxiosContext.Provider value={instance}> // <-- context value is instance
      {children}
    </AxiosContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default AxiosProvider; // <-- export the provider not the instance
```

To use just ensure that `AxiosProvider` wraps your application but within the `auth` provider. Use the `AxiosContext` to access the axios instance.

```
import { AxiosContext } from '../path/to/axios/instance";

...

const axiosInstance = useContext(AxiosContext);

...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.